# how do I make a text disappear and make different text appear by hovering over another text

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

How do I make a text disappear and make different text appear by hovering over another text.

```css
#a:hover + #b {
  display: none;
}
#c {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="a">Hover here</div>
  <div id="b">This will disappear</div>
  <div id="c">This will appear</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

So I guess this is what you are looking for:

```css
#a:hover + #b {
  display: none;
}
#a:hover ~ #c {
  display: block;
}
#c {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="a">Hover here</div>
  <div id="b">This will disappear</div>
  <div id="c">This will appear</div>
</body>
```

**Explanation**:
As you are already using the adjacent sibling selector (`+`) that selects the sibling element that immediately follows.

Using the general sibling selector (`~`) you can select from all the succeeding sibling elements.

Let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: If there's another "hover here" text(same function) but a different text like "Hover here 2".
I wanted to make "hover here 2" make the same "this will disappear" text disappear and make a different text appear again.

Sorry i'm not really good at explaining.

Comment: sorry, but I don't follow... maybe you can show me some code?

Comment: <html>
    <style>
    #a:hover + #b {
    display: none;
    }
    #a:hover ~ #c {
    display: block;
    }
    #c {
    display: none;
    }

    #d:hover + #b {
    display: none;
    }
    #d:hover ~ #e {
    display: block;
    }
    #e {
    display: none;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    <div id="a">Hover here</div>
    <div id="b">This will disappear</div>
    <div id="c">This will appear</div>

    <div id="d">Hover here2</div>
    <div id="e">This will appear2</div>

    </body>
    </html>

Comment: Here `#d:hover + #b {
    display: none;
  }` will not work as `b` preceeds `d`... you can only select siblings that follow an element using CSS.. otherwise you need JS :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a'),
 b = document.getElementById('b'),
 c = document.getElementById('c');
  
  
a.onmouseenter = function(){
 b.style.display = 'none';
  c.style.display = 'inherit';
}

a.onmouseleave = function(){
 b.style.display = 'inherit';
  c.style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
#c {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Hover here</div>
<div id="b">This will disappear</div>
<div id="c">This will appear</div>
```

This is how you do it using javascript. Hope it helps you.